# How to send proper response from Promise

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have axios to get data from Server in CustomerService.js

```
UpdateCustomer(customer){
        let vm = this;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            Axios.post("/members/update", customer)
            .then(function (response) {
                if (!response.success){
                    reject(response.message);
                }else{
                    resolve(vm.CommonService.parseJson(response.data));
                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                 reject(error);
            });
        });
    }
```

In my vue component file I am receving this rsponse but problem I am getting response in both then and catch and it throws error.

```
vm.CustomerService.UpdateCustomer({customer})
            .then(function (data) {           
                vm.app.Success("Success");
                vm.postCustomerTask(data);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {               
                vm.app.Fail(error);
            });
```

I am getting Json parse error. I dont seem to find exact problem. All I can think of is reject from UpdateCustomer is going in then in vue component.

Comment: is your response data a valid JSON?

Comment: on success, you want to reject??

Comment: You're parsing the response twice: `vm.CommonService.parseJson(response.data)` and `vm.postCustomerTask(JSON.parse(response.data))`. Unless the parsed "first" `response.data` has a property `data` containing JSON this will throw an parse error.

Comment: I have corrected the mistake I accidently changed during copy paste. I have added alert in both then and catch. First time I get proper Customer object than I get json parse error.

Comment: After changing the script a second time, the only possible spot for a parse error is `vm.CommonService.parseJson(response.data)`, hence the response from the server is not JSON.

Comment: Actually When I receive response in failure case it is json but in string format that's why I get error. Because I am performing few operation on customer Object and I get error that string.SomeProperty is not valid.

Comment: _" it is json but in string format"_ That's the nature of [JSON](http://json.org): _"JSON is a **text format** that is completely language independent..."_

Comment: I know Json is string but I am parsing JSON in resolve method so it should be an Object. But each time I get two results first time a json string and second time an object.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have wrong logic in the if-else statements. You have rejected under the `success` logic.

```
if (response.success){
   resolve(vm.CommonService.parseJson(response.data));
} else {
   reject(response.message);
}
```

Comment: I have corrected the mistake I accidently changed during copy paste.  I have added alert in both then and catch. First time I get proper Customer object than I get json parse error.